# What is the /proc/net/arp equivalent for ipv6 in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, ipv6

Is there any file in Linux that stores neighbor MAC address for IPV6 ? Like for IPV4 we have /proc/net/arp that stores the ARP entries. Are there any such files exist for IPv6 ?

Answer (score -1):

I think it is no good idea to access the proc-files directly.

Instead of using `arp` you can use `ip n`

For IPv6-only-entries: `ip -6 n`